# How to calculate total possible combination for an array integer

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation

Lets assume that the length of my array is 5 i.e a[5] and some random values in it {11,32,53,22,67}
The total number of possible combination here is 120(5*4*3*2*1)
How do I calculate all possible values ann store it

I have looked up on some previous code from geeksforgeeks and stackoverflow too but i could not find a solution

```
vector<int> people;
vector<int> combination;

void pretty_print(const vector<int>& v) {
  static int count = 0;
  cout << "combination no " << (++count) << ": [ ";
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { cout << v[i] << " "; }
  cout << "] " << endl;
}

void go(int offset, int k) {
  if (k == 0) {
    pretty_print(combination);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = offset; i <= people.size() - k; ++i) {
    combination.push_back(people[i]);
    go(i+1, k-1);
    combination.pop_back();
  }
}

int main() {
  int n = 5, k = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { people.push_back(i+1); }
  go(0, k);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code snippet was found online that helped me somewhat to find the combinations for 3 numbers . Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Well, you already answered your question. The number of possible permutations of an array of size x is x! (the factorial of x). So you need to find the factorial of `people.size()`.

Comment: It looks like you want a way to get [the permutations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) of the vector.

Comment: May be helpful to you [permutation and combination](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/)

Comment: is there anyone who can help me with code pls

Comment: i tried changing the size and all but couldn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this solution . https://notepad.pw/42f0zx9r. just add a counter 
to get your desired solution.

Comment: Please note link-only answers are not good here. The link may break and people need to go through a separate step to get the answer. All questions and answers should be self-contained enough that this doesn’t matter.

Comment: When i post my code. I got this error Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.@SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Did you do as instructed?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen would you explain the process to post code as an answer .I might be wrong

Comment: That worked like a charm @Sadiqul changing the prarameters now Tnx a lot mate